# Polar Plot: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I suspect that the answer to this is going to be "Don't use Matplotlib polar charts."

I'm trying to generate a polar plot [similar to this example plot](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html) and write the chart to a file.

```
"""
Demo of a line plot on a polar axis.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, r, color='r', linewidth=3)
ax.set_rmax(2.0)
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.savefig("/path/to/file/plot.png")
```

[image: Matplotlib Polar Chart]

When using `show()`, the figure will plot and a traceback appears in the shell.  When using `savefig()`, the traceback causes the `savefig()` operation to exit without completing--so no file is written.  It appears to be an error internal to `matplotlib` and simply converting the script to remove `numpy` isn't sufficient because `savefig()` is using `numpy` for polar plotting.
This example has worked fine on earlier versions of Mac OS (with presumably earlier versions of `numpy` ).

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- Trapping the `TypeError`.
- Converting `r` and `theta` to standard tuples and removing `numpy` from the script.

**WHAT I CAN'T TRY**

- Saving the fig from the Matplotlib `show()` view window (must use `savefig()` ).
- Upgrading Python
- Upgrading Matplotlib
- Downgrading numpy
- Downgrading Mac OS

Am I out of luck?

`Mac OS 10.15.7`
`Python 2.7`
`Matplotlib 1.3.1`
`numpy 1.16.6`

**UPDATE:** The above script runs fine on a different machine with this version of numpy:
`Mac OS 10.15.7`
`Python 2.7`
`Matplotlib 1.3.1`
`numpy 1.8.0rc1`

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is the traceback in all its verbosity.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled text 7", line 20, in <module>
    plt.savefig('/Path/To/File/plot.png')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1962, in print_png
    return agg.print_png(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 505, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1096, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axis.py", line 234, in draw
    self.gridline.draw(renderer)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/lines.py", line 550, in draw
    tpath, affine = transf_path.get_transformed_path_and_affine()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2562, in get_transformed_path_and_affine
    self._revalidate()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2539, in _revalidate
    self._transform.transform_path_non_affine(self._path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2230, in transform_path_non_affine
    self._a.transform_path(path))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2227, in transform_path_non_affine
    return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2230, in transform_path_non_affine
    self._a.transform_path(path))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/projections/polar.py", line 72, in transform_path_non_affine
    ipath = path.interpolated(path._interpolation_steps)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/path.py", line 553, in interpolated
    vertices = simple_linear_interpolation(self.vertices, steps)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1711, in simple_linear_interpolation
    result = np.zeros(new_shape, a.dtype)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

Comment: The current version for `numpy` is 1.19, but support for Py.2.7 is being dropped.  Matplotlib is 3.3.2.  So you are using old versions.   `numpy` has been tightened its rules for indexing.  Floats (e.g. 2.3) don't make sense as indexes, but old versions allowed you to use `2.0` instead of `2`.  If the error is caused by sloppiness in matplotlib, the only fix might be to get the right mix of versions.

Comment: Often we ask for a full traceback, to better see where the problem is occuring.  But this might be so buried in matplotlib calls that it might a pain to decipher.

Comment: @hpaulj - Thank you.  Unfortunately, this is for a project to be distributed across a broad array of machines running versions as old as described (and even older). Copy that on the traceback.  It's very long but I'm going to go ahead an add it for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new `numpy`, that last expression produces various results or errors:

```
In [108]: np.zeros(10)
Out[108]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

In [109]: np.zeros(10.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-109-6c3d535444cc>", line 1, in <module>
    np.zeros(10.)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

In [111]: np.zeros(np.array(10.))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-111-4250f3d71116>", line 1, in <module>
    np.zeros(np.array(10.))
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

In [112]: np.zeros(np.array([10.]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-112-e10bfdd4bb4f>", line 1, in <module>
    np.zeros(np.array([10.]))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: appreciate the investigation.  After much research, it seems that the only winning move is not to play.  Looks like I'll have to come up with an alternative solution.